# Decrypt directory with user password

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm looking for a way to encrypt the user directory on windows and be able to decrypt it with the login password. Is there a way to to that?

Comment: What you are looking for can be accomplished by using the EFS built into Windows.

Comment: Is the decryption key actually safe? I mean protected by the password and thus not usable?

Comment: What does your research indicate?  By default only the user's password can decrypt the files, if the password is reset, access to the files is lost unless a backup of the certificate is kept.  How you store and protect the certificate is entirely up to you.